# Getting Win32 API to draw a square on form

Tags: c#, winapi, gdi

Yes - I know this is not exciting - but my colleague can get the same psuedocode to work in a C program, it show a black square with some green bands - but in C# it only draws a black square - see below:

[image]

If you copy the code below in the partial class of Form1 (a fresh default Windows Application - you will see my problem.
I have tried a million different things - but I guess it how I have stipulated the Win32 calls or something - if anyone can help where I have gone wrong - I would be very grateful.

The code below looks very long but I have decided to put it all in so it is easy to just copy/paste into the partial class for a standard form - so don't let it scare you!

```
 public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        [DllImport("gdi32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        static extern IntPtr CreateDIBitmap([In] IntPtr hdc, [In] ref BITMAPINFOHEADER lpbmih, uint fdwInit, byte[] lpbInit, [In] ref BITMAPINFO lpbmi, uint fuUsage);

        [DllImport("gdi32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        static extern int SetDIBits(IntPtr hdc, IntPtr hbmp, uint uStartScan, uint
           cScanLines, byte[] lpvBits, [In] ref BITMAPINFO lpbmi, uint fuColorUse);

        [DllImport("gdi32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        static extern IntPtr CreateCompatibleDC(IntPtr hdc);

        [DllImport("gdi32.dll", ExactSpelling = true, PreserveSig = true, SetLastError = true)]
        static extern IntPtr SelectObject(IntPtr hdc, IntPtr hgdiobj);

        enum TernaryRasterOperations : uint
        {
            /// <summary>dest = source</summary>
            SRCCOPY = 0x00CC0020,
            /// <summary>dest = source OR dest</summary>
            SRCPAINT = 0x00EE0086,
            /// <summary>dest = source AND dest</summary>
            SRCAND = 0x008800C6,
            /// <summary>dest = source XOR dest</summary>
            SRCINVERT = 0x00660046,
            /// <summary>dest = source AND (NOT dest)</summary>
            SRCERASE = 0x00440328,
            /// <summary>dest = (NOT source)</summary>
            NOTSRCCOPY = 0x00330008,
            /// <summary>dest = (NOT src) AND (NOT dest)</summary>
            NOTSRCERASE = 0x001100A6,
            /// <summary>dest = (source AND pattern)</summary>
            MERGECOPY = 0x00C000CA,
            /// <summary>dest = (NOT source) OR dest</summary>
            MERGEPAINT = 0x00BB0226,
            /// <summary>dest = pattern</summary>
            PATCOPY = 0x00F00021,
            /// <summary>dest = DPSnoo</summary>
            PATPAINT = 0x00FB0A09,
            /// <summary>dest = pattern XOR dest</summary>
            PATINVERT = 0x005A0049,
            /// <summary>dest = (NOT dest)</summary>
            DSTINVERT = 0x00550009,
            /// <summary>dest = BLACK</summary>
            BLACKNESS = 0x00000042,
            /// <summary>dest = WHITE</summary>
            WHITENESS = 0x00FF0062,
            /// <summary>
            /// Capture window as seen on screen.  This includes layered windows
            /// such as WPF windows with AllowsTransparency="true"
            /// </summary>
            CAPTUREBLT = 0x40000000
        }

        [DllImport("gdi32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
        static extern bool BitBlt(IntPtr hdc, int nXDest, int nYDest, int nWidth, int nHeight, IntPtr hdcSrc, int nXSrc, int nYSrc, TernaryRasterOperations dwRop);

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        public struct BITMAPINFOHEADER
        {
            public uint biSize;
            public int biWidth;
            public int biHeight;
            public ushort biPlanes;
            public ushort biBitCount;
            public uint biCompression;
            public uint biSizeImage;
            public int biXPelsPerMeter;
            public int biYPelsPerMeter;
            public uint biClrUsed;
            public uint biClrImportant;

            public void Init()
            {
                biSize = (uint)Marshal.SizeOf(this);
            }
        }

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1)]
        public struct RGBQUAD
        {
            public byte rgbBlue;
            public byte rgbGreen;
            public byte rgbRed;
            public byte rgbReserved;
        }

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        public struct BITMAPINFO
        {
            public BITMAPINFOHEADER bmiHeader;
            public RGBQUAD bmiColors;
        }   

        [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        static extern IntPtr GetDC(IntPtr hWnd);

        [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        private static extern int ReleaseDC(IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr hDC);

        private System.IntPtr m_Bitmap;
        private BITMAPINFOHEADER m_Bmh;
        private BITMAPINFO m_Bmi = new BITMAPINFO();

        public Form1()
        {
            m_Bmh.Init();
            m_Bmh.biPlanes = 1;
            m_Bmh.biBitCount = 24;
            m_Bmh.biCompression = 0;
            m_Bmh.biHeight = 100;
            m_Bmh.biWidth = 100;

            m_Bitmap = (IntPtr)0;

            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {   
            int errorNumber = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();

            byte[] testGraphicArray = new byte[300];
            for (int i = 0; i < m_Bmh.biWidth; i++)
            {
                testGraphicArray[i * 3 + 0] = Convert.ToByte(i);
                testGraphicArray[i * 3 + 1] = Convert.ToByte(255 - i);
                testGraphicArray[i * 3 + 2] = Convert.ToByte(i);
            }

            IntPtr winPtr = GetDC(this.Handle);

            errorNumber = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();

            //Make the bitmap
            if (m_Bitmap == (IntPtr)0)
                m_Bitmap = CreateDIBitmap(winPtr, ref m_Bmh, (uint)0L, testGraphicArray, ref m_Bmi, (uint)0L);

            errorNumber = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();

            int retValue;
            //Set data to bitmap
            for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
            {
                retValue = SetDIBits((System.IntPtr)winPtr, m_Bitmap, (uint)i, 1, testGraphicArray, ref m_Bmi, (uint)0L);
            }

            errorNumber = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();

            // Draw the bitmap
            if (m_Bitmap != (IntPtr)0)
            {
                IntPtr hMemDC;
                IntPtr Old;

                hMemDC = CreateCompatibleDC((System.IntPtr)winPtr);

                Old = SelectObject(hMemDC, m_Bitmap);//Select out what was in DC

                bool success = BitBlt((System.IntPtr)winPtr, 10, 10, m_Bmh.biWidth, m_Bmh.biHeight, hMemDC, 0, 0, TernaryRasterOperations.SRCCOPY);
                errorNumber = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
                SelectObject(hMemDC, Old);//Put back in the previous stuff back into DC
            }

            ReleaseDC(this.Handle, winPtr);   
        }
```

Comment: It's a long story - but in short its a test program/control for something more advanced where I am overtaking the drawing function of another piece of software.

Comment: SetDIBits() fails, m_Bmi isn't inialized.  This is the hallmark of a "too localized" question, making this code work makes no sense.  Use System.Drawing.

Comment: @HansPassant - It's a good example piece of code to draw a bitmap with some colours inside it to a target device context.  So I think it could help people in that sense.  However the problem/error I have may be too localized, I admit, but thats down to my lack of knowledge for now.  I can't use System.Drawing - as the whole point is to use Win32 API.

Comment: @HansPassant - so m_Bmi is not initialised - but I thought I had done, when I put line "private BITMAPINFO m_Bmi = new BITMAPINFO();". Is there something I'm doing wrong here/misunderstanding about initialisation?

Comment: You forgot to set `biSizeImage` field to amount of bytes that your image will require in memory. Don't forget that each row of pixels should be aligned on 4 byte boundary. And why so negative? GDI has old interface, but it is easy to use, reasonably fast and under the hood uses same graphics engine as Direct2D now.

Answer (score 1):

Is the double-buffering style set?

If so, then .NET arranges for `e.Graphics` in `OnPaint` to be an in-memory DC, and after the `Paint` routine completes, .NET will overwrite everything on-screen from that in-memory layer.

Make sure your control styles are set appropriately.  I think you want `AllPaintingInWmPaint` turned on, and double buffering turned off.

You're missing a number of other things that are necessary for properly handling `WM_PAINT` using native APIs, though, such as using the device context returned by `BeginPaint` and later calling `EndPaint`.  You may need to handle `WM_PAINT` from `WndProc` and not let .NET dispatch it to `OnPaint` and the `Paint` event handlers.

I hope you're doing this to learn about the Win32 GDI APIs, and not because you plan to draw on .NET Forms with them in a finished application.

Comment: No - I have to learn Win32 API for what I want to do - I would never dream of doing this normally as it is mad! :)